# In Haskell terminology, what are monadic effects?

Tags: haskell

I feel I have a good understanding of monads, but I'm not too sure what is referred to by 'monadic effects'? Is this the evaluation of a monad? Does it have something to do with IO?

Comment: Effect is colloquial for the computational strategy of a monad. The Identity monad, for instance, doesn't pursue a specific strategy. It performs just normal function application without any modifications.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a value of type `M a` with `M` a `Monad` (or `Applicative` for applicative effects), then by effects we mean the information that is not contained in the `a` part. For example with `IO` it is very clear. A value of `IO Int` is an `Int` with some `IO` effects like writing to a file or firing missiles. A value of type `Maybe Int` is an Int with the effect of maybe actually not containing an `Int`. For `[Int]` the effect is, that you actually have multiple `Int`s.

We call this an effect because you can think of Monads and Applicatives as notions of computation with certain effects. For `Maybe` the effects are that you can abort the computation prematurely, for `[]` you can split the computation.

Comment: I don't like this "A value of `IO Int` is an `Int` with some `IO` effects" wording. An `IO Int` is no more an `Int` than `ls` is a list of files. It would be more accurate to call it a recipe for producing an `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to talk at the question several ways, and hopefully it's helpful.

An "effect" (as in "side-effects") refer to the behaviors of a *specific instance* of `Monad`, so e.g. the `State` monad expresses the effect of "stateful computation" with `get` and `put`. Monad transformer libraries like `mtl` can be thought of as ways of "composing effects".

Without knowing the types (or in fact reading the docs) for `foo` and `bar` here, we can't say anything about what "monadic effects" are happening here, even though we can say quite a few other things about this code:

```
do a <- fmap bar $ foo x
   b <- baz
   return (a,b)
```

The `do` block above has a type of the form `SomeMonad m=> m (a,b)`. That tuple `(a,b)` that is "returned", and the way it can be passed to another "effectful computation" with `>>=`, is not what we're talking about when we talk about "effects".

Monadic effects always actually "happen" when you `run` them (by calling `runState` for `State` for instance).

In the case of `IO` only the runtime has access to the particular `run` function for `IO`, so the nonexistent `runIO` function calls `main` to run your program. For `IO` the "monadic effects" are truly the same as what in other languages you'd call "side-effects", i.e. just about anything that might change the state of the world.

Comment: Would `Maybe` have any monadic effect? It doesn't have any `run` method which adds a bit of confusion.

Comment: You're right, I almost went back to edit that in light of `Maybe` and `[]` but don't really have a good quick clarification (but certainly that sentence is not really accurate). `Maybe` expresses the effect of computations which can fail (or computation in a language with `null`)